# Kafka Streams internal topic naming for KTable-Ktable foreign key join

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka 2.4.1 (Confluent 5.4.1) and am trying to implement a KTable to KTable join using  the new foreign key join functionality.
It works great locally, however due to company policy I have to set the topic name:

```
a.join(b,
       keyExtractor,
       this::map,
       Named.as("joiner"),
       joinStore);
```

The issue is

1. The topic is created as expected: [application.id]-"joiner"-[suffix]
2. However, when registering the schema to the schema registry, only the "joiner"-[suffix] is used as a subject. This is an issue because company policy requires the application.id to be set as a given value.

Is it a bug? At least, this behavior seems to be inconsistent with other named store (Materialized, Grouped).

Update 1:

Apparently this is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9390
I'll try to upgrade and see if it solves mine.

Update 2:

Upgrading to kafka streams 5.5.1-css from the confluent repo fixed the issue. I'll switch back to the apache kafka releases once https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8574 is released there, as it was the blocking issue.